# how to calculate XOR (dyadic) convolution with time complexity O(n log n)

Tags: algorithm, divide-and-conquer

[image]

“⊕” is the bitwise XOR operation.

I think Karatsuba’s algorithm may be used to solve the problem, but when I try to use XOR instead of "+" in the Karatsuba’s algorithm, it is tough to get the sub-problem.

Comment: Karatsuba's algorithm isn't `O(n log n)`.

Answer (score 3):

The [convolution theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem) gives you

```
F(C) = F(A) . F(B)
```

where `F` is a Fourier-related transform, in this case the Hadamard transform, and `.` is point-wise multiplication. Using the [fast Walsh–Hadamard transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Walsh%E2%80%93Hadamard_transform), you can compute `F(A)`, `F(B)`, and finally `C` (using the inverse), in `O(n log n)` operations. The point-wise multiplication is simply `O(n)`.