# count all pairs with given xor range (0-k)

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, xor

Given an array `A` of size `n` and an integer `k`, how can we count for each `x` from `0` to `k` the number of pairs `(A[i], A[j])` such that `i < j` and `A[i] XOR A[j] = x`?

For example, given the array `A = [1, 2, 3]` and `k = 2`, there are

```
0 pairs with XOR 0
1 pair with XOR 1 (2 XOR 3)
1 pair with XOR 2 (1 XOR 3),
```

so the result is `[0, 1, 1]`.

I have an `O(n^2)` solution but am looking for a more efficient one.

Comment: What do you mean xor 2? What’s the role of k here? Sorry don’t understand your question.

Comment: @srv236 1 xor 3 gives 2 . xor 2 is the result of 1xor3.

Comment: and the role of k is that we need to find result for each and every number from 0 to k, that 's why the output is 0 1 1

Comment: It might help to understand the task and the problem if you share your current implementation.

Comment: @Zabuzard probably something like `collections.Counter(a^b for (i, a) in enumerate(A) for (j, b) in enumerate(A) if i < j and a^b <= k)`.

Comment: this  is a misuse of the StackOverflow community because this question is  HackerEarth Vimeo Full Stack Developer Hiring Challenge which is active till 13 Sept 2020.

Comment: @PDP Oops... Should I post the answer I am just writing?

Comment: @PDP i am not here to cheat , i just wanted to know to an efficient solution .

Answer (score 0):

Let `C` be the frequencies of `A`, i.e. `C[x] = count(A[i] == x)`.

Then the problem become XOR convolution of `C` and `C`, and subtract `len(A)` from the result of index `0` since it contains pairs `(i,j)` where `i==j`.

And XOR convolution can be solved by [Fast Walsh–Hadamard transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Walsh%E2%80%93Hadamard_transform), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53592544).

Finally, the complexity is `O(n + m log m)` where the `m` is `len(C)` and equal to `max(A)`.

Comment: Any way that challenge ended. There is nothing that stop me from posting this answer.