# How do I optimize this XOR sum algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, math, time-complexity, xor

I'm trying to solve this hackerrank problem https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/xor-subsequence/problem

```
from functools import reduce

def xor_sum(arr):
    return reduce(lambda x,y: x^y, arr)    

def xorSubsequence(arr):
    freq = {}
    max_c = float("-inf") # init val
    min_n = float("inf") # init val
    
    for slice_size in range(1, len(arr)+1):
        for step in range(0, len(arr)+1-slice_size):
            n = xor_sum(arr[i] for i in range(step,step+slice_size))
            
            freq[n] = freq.get(n,0)+1
            if freq[n] >= max_c and (n < min_n or freq[n]> max_c):
                min_n = n
                max_c = freq[n]

    return  min_n, freq[min_n]
```

But it times out since it's ~O(n^3).
I feel like there is some math trick, can someone explain the solution to me? I tried to read some solutions in the discussion but I didn't quite get them.

Problem copy:

> Consider an array, ***A***, of ***n*** integers (*A=a<sub>0</sub>,a<sub>1</sub>,...,a<sub>n-1</sub>*). We take
> all consecutive subsequences of integers from the array that satisfy the following:
> {*a<sub>i</sub>,a<sub>i+1</sub>,...,a<sub>j-1</sub>,a<sub>j</sub>*}, where 0≤*i≤j≤n*
>
> For each subsequence, we apply the bitwise XOR (⊕) operation
> on all the integers and record the resultant value.
>
> Given array ***A***, find the XOR sum of every subsequence of
> ***A*** and determine the frequency at which each number occurs.
> Then print the number and its respective frequency
> as two space-separated values on a single line.
>
> Output Format
>
> Print 2 space-separated integers on a single line.
> The first integer should be the number having the highest frequency,
> and the second integer should be the number's frequency
> (i.e., the number of times it appeared).
> If there are multiple numbers having maximal frequency,
> choose the smallest one.
>
> Constraints
>
> • 1≤n≤10<sup>5</sup>
> • 1≤a<sub>i</sub><2<sup>16</sup>

Comment: Oh, wow. I don't fully understand it yet myself, but apparently this is key: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Walsh%E2%80%93Hadamard_transform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Why Xor sum is Dyadic convolution

Denote the input array as `a`.

Construct an array `b`, such that `b[i]=a[0]⊕a[1]⊕...⊕a[i]`. One can then construct a list `M`, `M[i]` stands for the number of element in `b` which has a value `i`. Note that some zero-padding is added to make the length of M be a power of 2.

Then consider the Dyadic (XOR) convolution. The difinition is(picture taken form [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53591757/9758790))：
[image]

Consider conduct this Dyadic convolution between `M` and `M`, i.e. `N=M*M` where `*` stands for Dyadic convolution. Then `N[i]` is the sum of `M[j]M[k]` over all `(j,k)` that `j⊕k=i`.

Consider each subsequence `xor(a[p:q])`, we have `xor(a[p:q])=b[p]⊕b[q]`. For Every integer `i`, all the consecutive subsequences the xor results of which are equal to `i` can be converted to in this form(`i=xor(a[p:q])=b[p]⊕b[q]`). We further group this family of subsequences by the value of `b[p]` and the value `b[q]`,  for example, if `xor(a[p1:q1])=xor(a[p2,q2])=i`, and if `b[p1]=b[p2],b[q1]=b[q2]`, these two subsequences will be grouped in the same sub-group. Consider sub-group `(j,k)`, where the subsequences can be represented in the form`i=xor(a[p':q'])=b[p']⊕b[q'], b[p']=j, b[q']=k`, the number of subsquences in this sub-group `(j,k)` is `M[j]M[k]` (Recall that `M[i]` stands for the number of element in `b` which has a value `i`). So `N[i]` is the number sequence `a[p:q]` that `xor(a[p:q])=i`.

Howvever, since `a[p:q]` and `a[q:p]` are identical, we count every subsequence twice. So `N[i]` is twice of "number of consecutive subsequences that xor get i".

### Use FWHT to compute the convolution

So now what we need is compute `N=M*M`, according to The Dyadic (XOR) convolution theorem(see proof [here](https://am-just-a-nobody.blogspot.com/2016/07/dyadic-xor-convolution-theorem.html)), we can first perform compute `H(N)=H(M)×H(M)`. As `H` is involutive(see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_transform)), to get `N` just apply `H` on `H(N)` again.

### Analysis of code

In this section, I will analysis the code provided by @Kache.

Actually, `b` is  `accumulate([0] + seq, xor)`.  Using `histogram = Counter(accumulate([0] + seq, xor))`, one can get a dict of `{possible_value_in_b: num_of_occurrence}`. Then the next line, `histogram = [histogram[value] for value in range(next_pow2)]`, this is the `M` mentioned above with padding added.

Then in `histogram = [x * x for x in fwht(histogram)]`, so now histogram is `H(N)`. And `histogram = [y // next_pow2 for y in fwht(histogram)]` serves as inverse transformation.

this is what `histogram = [y // next_pow2 for y in fwht(histogram)]` do.

The `histogram[0] -= len(seq) + 1` eliminate the influence of the fact that `a[p:p]=0`. And `histogram = [y // 2 for y in histogram]` avoid counting twice (as stated before, `N[i]` counts `a[p:q]` and `a[q:p]` separately).

Answer (score 5):

The solution uses two tricks.

The first trick is to compute the n+1 prefix sums σ[0], …, σ[n] (as `tobias_k` notes), but with XOR instead of + (e.g., σ[2] = a[0] XOR a[1] XOR a[2]). The sublist from i to j has XOR-sum equal to σ[i−1] XOR σ[j]. If we loop i−1 and j over all possible pairs of values 0, …, n without considering the constraint i ≤ j, we get each sublist twice (once “forward”, once “backward”) and also n+1 extra zeros from when i−1 = j.

The second trick is that a fast Walsh–Hadamard transform can solve the following problem in O(n log n) time: given a list X and a list Y, we want the frequency counts of x XOR y for (x, y) ∈ X × Y. (For this problem, X = Y, but the structure of this trick is clearer if I use separate variables.) Why should we suspect that there is a fast algorithm in the first place? Limits aside, if it were x + y instead of x XOR y, then we would be looking to multiply polynomials quickly.

Let’s replace the list X with its frequency vector f, and Y with its frequency vector g. For example, X = [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 3] becomes f = [3, 0, 2, 1]. Assuming that f and g have four elements, the desired result is

```
[f[0] g[0] + f[1] g[1] + f[2] g[2] + f[3] g[3]
,f[0] g[1] + f[1] g[0] + f[2] g[3] + f[3] g[2]
,f[0] g[2] + f[1] g[3] + f[2] g[0] + f[3] g[1]
,f[0] g[3] + f[1] g[2] + f[2] g[1] + f[3] g[0]
].
```

This is an example of an algebraic object called a symmetric bilinear form, which means that there exists some basis-changing matrix B such that the desired result is B⁻¹ (B f * B g), where * denotes element-wise multiplication. (Spoiler: B is a Walsh matrix.)

For intuition about the fast Walsh–Hadamard transform, which for every vector v can compute B v efficiently, let me show you what happens when I add the first two elements of the result:

```
f[0] g[0] + f[1] g[1] + f[2] g[2] + f[3] g[3]
+ f[0] g[1] + f[1] g[0] + f[2] g[3] + f[3] g[2]
= f[0] (g[0] + g[1]) + f[1] (g[1] + g[0]) + f[2] (g[2] + g[3]) + f[3] (g[3] + g[2])
= (f[0] + f[1]) (g[0] + g[1]) + (f[2] + f[3]) (g[2] + g[3])
```

and add the second two elements:

```
f[0] g[2] + f[1] g[3] + f[2] g[0] + f[3] g[1]
+ f[0] g[3] + f[1] g[2] + f[2] g[1] + f[3] g[0]
= f[0] (g[2] + g[3]) + f[1] (g[3] + g[2]) + f[2] (g[0] + g[1]) + f[3] (g[1] + g[0])
= (f[0] + f[1]) (g[2] + g[3]) + (f[2] + f[3]) (g[0] + g[1])
```

and subtract the first two elements:

```
f[0] g[0] + f[1] g[1] + f[2] g[2] + f[3] g[3]
− (f[0] g[1] + f[1] g[0] + f[2] g[3] + f[3] g[2])
= f[0] (g[0] − g[1]) + f[1] (g[1] − g[0]) + f[2] (g[2] − g[3]) + f[3] (g[3] − g[2])
= (f[0] − f[1]) (g[0] − g[1]) + (f[2] − f[3]) (g[2] − g[3])
```

and subtract the second two elements:

```
f[0] g[2] + f[1] g[3] + f[2] g[0] + f[3] g[1]
− (f[0] g[3] + f[1] g[2] + f[2] g[1] + f[3] g[0])
= f[0] (g[2] − g[3]) + f[1] (g[3] − g[2]) + f[2] (g[0] − g[1]) + f[3] (g[1] − g[0])
= (f[0] − f[1]) (g[2] − g[3]) + (f[2] − f[3]) (g[0] − g[1]) .
```

If we let `f′ = [f[0] + f[1], f[2] + f[3]]` and `g′ = [g[0] + g[1], g[2] + g[3]]`, then the first two quantities are `[f′[0] g′[0] + g′[1] g′[1], f′[0] g′[1] + f′[1] g′[0]]`, which is the same problem but half as large. Ditto the second two quantities. Finally, we can recover

```
x = f[0] g[0] + f[1] g[1] + f[2] g[2] + f[3] g[3]
y = f[0] g[1] + f[1] g[0] + f[2] g[3] + f[3] g[2]
```

from `x + y` and `x − y` as `x = ((x + y) + (x − y))/2` and `y = ((x + y) − (x − y))/2` (and likewise for all of the other pairs). (Note that `Kache`’s code defers the division to the end so that it can reuse the same transform.)

Answer (score 2):

Note that your algorithms is not O(n²) but O(n³), but you can reduce it to O(n²) by just xor-ing each new number to all the results from the last "slice" (plus that number itself, starting a new subsequence).

```
from collections import Counter
def xor_sub_sum(arr):
    freq = Counter()
    last = []
    for x in arr:
        last = [x, *(x^y for y in last)]
        freq.update(last)
    # "most_common" does not consider smallest-key constraint...
    return max(freq.items(), key=lambda t: (t[1], -t[0]))
```

On my machine, this reduces the execution time for 1000 elements from 21.7 seconds to just 0.05 seconds. For 10000, it still takes ~5 seconds, though.

Comment: Nice optimization but yes it still times out on big testcases

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I still don't fully understand it, but I was able to pass all the tests by implementing an `O(n log(n))` `fwht()` based on Wikipedia's description, plus pulling from another existing solution:

```py
from collections import Counter
from itertools import accumulate
from operator import xor


def fwht(arr):
    # https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Walsh%E2%80%93Hadamard_transform
    if len(arr) == 1:
        return arr

    prefix, suffix = arr[:len(arr) // 2], arr[len(arr) // 2:]

    new_prefix = fwht([p + s for p, s in zip(prefix, suffix)])
    new_suffix = fwht([p - s for p, s in zip(prefix, suffix)])
    return new_prefix + new_suffix


def xorSubsequence(seq):
    next_pow2 = 2**(len(seq) - 1).bit_length()

    histogram = Counter(accumulate([0] + seq, xor))
    histogram = [histogram[value] for value in range(next_pow2)]

    histogram = [x * x for x in fwht(histogram)]
    histogram = [y // next_pow2 for y in fwht(histogram)]

    histogram[0] -= len(seq) + 1             # self combos (diagonal in table)
    histogram = [y // 2 for y in histogram]  # don't count things twice

    max_freq = max(histogram)
    return next((i, freq) for i, freq in enumerate(histogram) if freq == max_freq)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll add a bounty in a couple of days to see if someone can add an explanation.

Comment: `next_pow2` should be `2**max(seq).bit_length()`.

Answer (score -1):

I propose this as a functional bitwise xor sum of subsequence between indexes `l` and `r`.

```
# Sequence (An)n is defined by A(n)=A(n-1)^n with ^ bitwise xor operation
# Compute bitwise xor of subsequence of consecutive sequence elements
# ...between a left and right index, A(k), k=l..r, i.e., A(l)^A(l+1)^...^A(r-1)^A(r)

#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

# Hints ##
# Notice how to bitwise xor of consecutive integers in range 1..n simplifies
# e.g., printing out bitwise xor of consecutive integers in 1..13
# 0 1 3 0 4 1 7 0 8 1 11 0 12
# ...someting happens, some pattern wrt n%4
# Method comp_xor_in_range(n) shows a corresponding fast implementation
# for bitwise xor of consecutive integers in range 1..n

# Then, notice how bitwise xor of (An)n subsequence elements simplifies, depending on 
# ...parity of left index and parity of number of elements in subsequence 

# compute bitwise xor of elements in range 1..n
def comp_xor_in_range(l):
    res=l%4
    if res==0:
        return l
    elif res==1:
        return 1
    elif res==2:
        return l+1
    else:
        return 0

# compute bitwise xor of elements in range l(eft)..r
def comp_xor_in_range_lr(l,r):
    return comp_xor_in_range(l-1)^comp_xor_in_range(r)

#compute bitwise xor of even elements in range 1..n 
def comp_xor_even_in_range(l):
    res=l%2
    if res==0:
        return 2*comp_xor_in_range(l//2)
    else:
        return 2*comp_xor_in_range((l-1)//2)
    
# compute bitwise xor of even elements in range l(eft)..r
def comp_xor_even_in_range_lr(l,r):
    return comp_xor_even_in_range(l-1)^comp_xor_even_in_range(r)

#compute bitwise xor of odd elements in range 1..n 
def comp_xor_odd_in_range(l):
    return comp_xor_even_in_range(l)^comp_xor_in_range(l)

# compute bitwise xor of even elements in range l(eft)..r
def comp_xor_odd_in_range_lr(l,r):
    return comp_xor_odd_in_range(l-1)^comp_xor_odd_in_range(r)

def xorSequence(l, r):
    n=r-l+1
    
    if n%2==0:
        if l%2==0:
            return comp_xor_odd_in_range_lr(l,r)
        else:
            return comp_xor_even_in_range_lr(l,r)
    else:
        if l%2==0:
            return comp_xor_even_in_range_lr(l+1,r)^comp_xor_in_range(l)
        else:
            return comp_xor_odd_in_range_lr(l+1,r)^comp_xor_in_range(l)


    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    q = int(input())

    for q_itr in range(q):
        lr = input().split()

        l = int(lr[0])

        r = int(lr[1])

        result = xorSequence(l, r)

        fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: It precisely solves the problem, maybe that's enough

Comment: It absolutely doesn't. You're not even reading the input correctly. You pretend that there are l/r pairs instead of array values.

Comment: Well, anyone with a br... and ten fingers can slightly arrange.

Comment: How? Your solution relies on the array values being a specific pattern, no? How do you "slightly arrange" it so that it can solve the problem's  **arbitrary** array values?